# AngularJS Dependency Injection for directive and controllers

Tags: angularjs

Say I have:

```
<body ng-app>
    <block-type-1>...</block-type-1>
    <block-type-2>...</block-type-1>
    <block-type-3>...</block-type-1>
```

Some of these blocks are rendered on the server side, and some are rendered from `templateUrl`. Each block has its own set of functions, but there are also some functions that all blocks share (for example, if you click on the header of each block, it toggles the entire block. So all should have this functionality).

I can't figure out how to share these common functions for the blocks that are rendered from `templateUrl`! The other blocks are okay because I can set a controller on the `<body>` tag and they will work fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you create services for your application to share common functionality across controllers and directives.

The example below shows how services are created via `factory()` method takes advantage in sharing functionality all over the application. You can choose to inject your services in your directives and controllers, as shown in directives `block-type-1` and `block-type-2` and the controller `MyController`. The controller invokes the toggle function of the  `Common` service using the `$scope.toggle()` such that it affects the expressions that depends on the value change in the Service.

The directive templates: `<block-type-1>` and `<block-type-2>` invokes the `Common` service function `Common.getToggle()` wherein the value returned is affected by the changes of the `toggled` variable via `Common.toggle()`. This is the reason behind the change of the expression of both directives when the  toggle was clicked because it invokes `Common.toggle()`.

Example: Check the associated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkB5iEZ4vlYSH15LJ4ep?p=preview) demo.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <block-type-1></block-type-1>
    <block-type-2></block-type-2>
    <block-type-3></block-type-3>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', []).

factory('Common', function() {
    var toggled = false;
    return {
        toggle: function() { 
            toggled = !toggled; 
        },
        getToggle: function() {
            return toggled? 'toggled': 'untoggled';
        }
    };
}).

controller('MyController', function($scope, Common) {
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        Common.toggle();
    };
}).

directive('blockType1', function(Common) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.Common = Common;
        },
        template: '<div>{{Common.getToggle()}} from block-type-1</div>'
    };
}).

directive('blockType2', function(Common) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.Common = Common;
        },
        template: '<div>{{Common.getToggle()}} - From block-type-2</div>'
    };
}).

directive('blockType3', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {},
        template: '<div>block-type-3: Im unaffected by the toggle</div>'
    };
});
```